# Terminating app due to uncaught exception when I run my cpp file

Tags: macos, qt, macos-mojave

I was trying to use vtk to visualize a pcd(type of Point Cloud Data) data file on Qt creator. But it popped out some weird errors. Here is the output:

```
2018-12-25 01:06:59.667 test6[10199:1376847] *** Terminating app due                to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:    'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4dadbecd     __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff79b97720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4daf595d -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff4aff6c8e -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 324
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff4aff407c -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1488
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff4aff3aa6 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45
    6   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.1.1.dylib  0x000000010b7bbbae _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow13CreateAWindowEv + 2136
    7   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.1.1.dylib  0x000000010b7bc1db _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow10InitializeEv + 205
    8   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.1.1.dylib  0x000000010b7b9cb0 _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow5StartEv + 18
    9   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.1.1.dylib  0x000000010b7b834c _ZN30vtkCocoaRenderWindowInteractor10InitializeEv + 56
    10  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010c1ec797 _ZN3pcl13visualization13PCLVisualizer16createInteractorEv + 213
    11  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010c1ec34e _ZN3pcl13visualization13PCLVisualizerC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEb + 490
    12  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010c2100f3 _ZN3pcl13visualization11CloudViewer16CloudViewer_implclEv + 49
    13  libboost_thread-mt.dylib            0x000000010da602c8 _ZN5boost12_GLOBAL__N_112thread_proxyEPv + 136
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7ae59305 _pthread_body + 126
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7ae5c26f _pthread_start + 70
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7ae58415     thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any ideas about that?
My Computer is Mojave 10.14.2

Answer (score 4):

The underlying problem is that all AppKit/GUI calls need to happen from the main thread, but your app is calling AppKit from a non-main thread. I’m not sure if this is a problem from your code or one of the libraries you’re using though.